# jshashtable.each use existing function

Tags: javascript, hashtable, each

So I have a `Hashtable` defined (with jshashtable.js):

```
hashy = new Hashtable();
```

I put some keys in it:

```
hashy.put("hi", "yay");
hashy.put("hello", "yes");
```

Now I want to iterate it with .each, as the doc says:

```
hashy.each(iterator());
```

But it says '**object is not a function**'

Now, if I do this:

```
hashy.each(function() { });
```

It works, but is there a way to call an existing function this way?

Answer (score 0):

I just realized the most obvious answer would be to do:

hashy.each(function() { iterator(); });

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `iterator` function is something like the following:

```
function iterator(key, value) {
    // Do something with key and/or value
}
```

... then just pass the function in without the parentheses. With the parentheses, you're executing the function immediately (just once) and passing the returned value into `each()`, which is probably not what you intended.

```
hashy.each(iterator);
```